# Getting an Object error when attempting to find ID Value in Workspace

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to find an object in the workspace by using a value.
When printing the value, it prints out the value "WM830" as a string.
But it's not finding the model in the workspace.

This is the code:

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    local busId = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Car.value
    game.Workspace[busId].Body.Display.maindest.SurfaceGUI.TextLabel.text = "Woop"
end)
```

This is the error:
`Players.E_Link.PlayerGui.A-Chassis Interface.NXUI.TextButton.Script:3: bad argument #2 to '?' (string expected, got Object)`

Comment: Turns out it was using the wrong value entity. I miss licked and Roblox makes all values appear the same.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you to try to break up your path to the TextLabel into more reliable chunks :

```
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    -- find the name of the bus for this button
    local busId = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Car.value
    local bus = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(busId)

    if bus then
        -- if we find the bus, update the label on the bus
        -- NOTE - IF THIS NEXT LINE FAILS, CONTINUE TO BREAK UP THIS PATH INTO SMALLER PIECES
        local busDestLabel = bus.Body.Display.maindest.SurfaceGUI.TextLabel
        busDestLabel.Text = "Woop"
    else
        -- Couldn't find the bus, check that the bus actually exists in the workspace
        warn("Could not find a bus with id : ", busId)
    end
end)
```

This way, your error message can fail closer to what part of the path is actually missing. It's also good practice to verify that the part/model you are going to work with actually exists before trying to get or set properties on it.